# ngModelOptions with Input in Angular form

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm getting this suggestion in the developer-console when using angular template-driven form and not writing **'name'** attribute but, I'm using **[(ngModel)]** with the input field.

```
control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

 Example 1: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first">
 Example 2: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

If I'm using 'name' attribute or `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` then working fine.

**But I'm not sure why that suggestion is occuring?**

Comment: From the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/forms#naming-control-elements): "When you use `[(ngModel)]` on an element, you **must define** a name attribute for that element". Else Angular understand that you're not using template driven form. This is the reason because suggest use `{standalone:true}`. Inside a Reactive Forms we can use an input with `[(ngModel)]` if the variable don't belong to the FormGroup, but in this case is **obligatory** use the `[ngModelOptions]`

Answer (score 1):

```
If i could see your whole form code,i could explain more clearly. 

 Assuming you are using [formGroup] directive,then
```

This error could come if you are mentioning formControlName for only some fields in the form and not for all.
        Angular expects us to use formContorl in the reactive form and you are using ngModel . Since it cannot get an instance of formControl, its asking you to mention [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}".
        You can achieve same thing with formControl without ngModel binding for fields also.

```
    https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms
```

Comment: Hi, 

I'm using template driven form