# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input' in VSC

Tags: angular

There are several messages on this problem in StackOverFlow, but I'm still stuck.

I have the error message

```
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'
```

On my first laptop I don't have an error message but on my second laptop "yes", I don't understand why?

[the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiBhu.jpg)

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-login">
  <form (ngSubmit)="login()">

    <div class="input_field">
      <label>Identification de l'agent </label>
      <input type="text" class="input" id="user" name="user" [(ngModel)]="loginForm.user" required maxlength="4">
     </div>

     <div class="btn">
      <input type="submit" value="Connexion" class="sign_btn">
     </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-singin',
    templateUrl: './singin.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./singin.component.css']
})
export class SinginComponent implements OnInit {
    loginForm: Login = new Login();
    ngUnsubscribe = new Subject < void > ();

    constructor(private log: SessionService, private store: Store, private router: Router) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {}

    login(): void {
        this.log.login(this.loginForm)
            .pipe(
                takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe),
            ).subscribe(
                res => {
                    if (res.islogged === true) {
                        this.store.dispatch(new SessionAction(res))
                        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
                    } else {
                        alert("L'identifiant est incorrect ! ")
                    }
                }
            )
    }
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48703803/ngmodeloptions-with-input-in-angular-form), by using `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` it should work. I tried but I still have the same error message.

```
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'
```

How could I get rid of this error message, please?

**EDIT**

In the app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgxsModule } from '@ngxs/store';

import { SessionState } from './store/session/session.state';
import { CanActivateTeam } from './core/canActivateTeam.guard';
import { NgxsStoragePluginModule } from '@ngxs/storage-plugin';
import { IsActivate } from './core/isActivate.guard';

import { IdentityModule } from './views/identity/identity.module';
import { AppHttpInterceptor } from './core/interceptor/app-http.interceptor';
import { FormFollowUpModule } from './views/dashboard/views/dta/views/form-follow-up/form-follow-up.module';
import { FormCreateModule } from './views/dashboard/views/dta/views/form-create/form-create.module';
import { FormDeleteModule } from './views/dashboard/views/dta/views/form-delete/form-delete.module';

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';



@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
IdentityModule,
HttpClientModule,
FormsModule,
NgxsModule.forRoot([SessionState], {
developmentMode: true
}),
NgxsStoragePluginModule.forRoot({
key: 'session'
}),
FormFollowUpModule,
FormCreateModule,
FormDeleteModule,

],
providers: [
CanActivateTeam,
IsActivate,
{
provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
useClass: AppHttpInterceptor,
multi: true

}
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.html**

I have an error message also

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kU3QP.jpg)

**identity.module.ts**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { SessionService } from '../../services/sessions.service';
import { IdentityRoutingModule } from './identity-routing.module';
import { IdentityComponent } from './identity.component';
import { SinginComponent } from './view/singin/singin.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    IdentityComponent,
    SinginComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    FormsModule,
    IdentityRoutingModule

  ],
  providers: [
    SessionService
  ]
})
export class IdentityModule { }
```

Comment: What is the name of the module that the `SinginComponent` is declared in?

Comment: @R. Richards: In `IdentityModule`... I edited first message with this module.

Comment: It's looks like an error in your editor. If you're using Visual Studio Code you can add the [Angular Snippets by John Papa](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.Angular2) or another similar extension